# How to debug CarPlay app on actual device

Tags: ios, carplay

Is there any way to run the car play app on actual device.
I am able to run the app on car play simulator, but my app does not appear on actual head unit device. I have a development provisioning profile entitled for car play, it runs on iOS device, but does not appear on head unit.

I have searched on internet, but did not find any good post regarding this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you added a new record to you project's Entitlements file?
I mean `com.apple.developer.carplay-maps` type of `Boolean` with value `YES`

Comment: What type of CarPlay app are you trying? Audio? Navigation?

Comment: Issue solved ???

Answer (score 2):

You need to contact Apple directly via the form you can find under this url: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/adding_carplay_support_to_your_navigation_app

there you have to describe the use case of your app. If apple approve it you get a special entitlement that you can use in the developer portal to build a working provisioning profile.